# How do I instruct MSTest to remove all testing artifacts after a test run?

Tags: mstest

I am running MSTest against our test assembly from the command line:

`mstest /testcontainer:C:\dev\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll`

This works fine, except I do not want the artifacts from this run to remain.  Seems that MSTest leaves a copy around.  For me, they're in the `C:\dev\TestResults\` directory.

I have investigated a few things:

- Configuration in a `.testsettings` file.  Couldn't find anything there.
- Running a cleanup script, specified in a `.testsettings` file.  This would work, but how can I find the output location MSTest uses for the artifacts?
- Using Visual Studio to limit the number of old test results in Tools > Options > Test Tools > Test Execution.  This doesn't work when using `mstest.exe` - and it wouldn't work anyway, as I want to script this for other developers on our team.

How can I remove test run artifacts after the run is completed?

*Edit: also, I would accept an answer that will run our MSTest tests using an open source test running tool.  I just want to script this, man.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSTest creates the TestResults directory in $pwd.

```
function global:runtests()
{
    $mstest = Join-Path $env:VS100COMNTOOLS "..\IDE\mstest.exe" -Resolve

    $resultsDir = Join-Path $pwd "TestResults"

    $testDll = Join-Path $solutionScriptsContainer "..\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" -Resolve          
    $output = & $mstest /testcontainer:$testDll 
    $o = [regex]::match($output, "^.*(Summary.*)Results file.*$")
    $mstflag = "MSTest:"
    $op =  $mstflag +=  $o.groups[1].value

    Write-Host $op
    Write-Host "Deleting $resultsDir"

    remove-item $resultsDir -force -recurse
}
```

Comment: You can also append a simple rd batch command: `mstest /testcontainer:C:\dev\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll&&rd /s /q "C:\dev\TestResults"`